# Por que meu rodapé não está ficando na tela inteira?

Tags: css

Estou tentando fazer meu rodapé pegar 100% da tela, mas dependendo da resolução fica faltando uma parte, como na imagem 2, o código CSS que estou usando no rodapé é esse:

```
footer {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   font-family:Gabriola;
   font-size:25px;
   color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
   background: rgba(73,155,234,1);
   background-size:cover;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(53,135,214,1);
}
```

<kbd>[image: Rodapé 100% da tela]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: Imagem com erro, não ocupa 100% da largura da tela.]</kbd>

Estou fazendo algo errado, ou é um bug? rsrs

Comment: Depende de como está seu documento, esse `width: 100%` é relativo a onde esse elemento está. Ele está no `<body>` ou dentro de outro elemento?

Comment: Renan, esse erro estava acontecendo por causa de um height:100%; dentro do body, quando removi ficou perfeito! Não sei bem porque esse height 100% causou isso, não entendo muito sobre html! Mas obrigado a todos que tentaram me ajudar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A mais Rápida e curta Solução:

A mais rápida **e suja** solução para resolver isto, seria aplicar um `position:absolute;`([ler sobre *positions*](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)),  ao `footer`. No entanto não tenho 100% certeza de que irá solucionar o problema pois irá depender de vários aspectos, como estilos aplicados a elementos anteriores a este elemento, etc.

> Será também necessário aplicar uma `margin-bottom` ao `body` ou o elemento *wrapper/container* que 'segura' todo o conteúdo, consoante o tamanho do `footer` para evitar que o conteúdo do corpo seja sobreposto pelo `footer`.
> Por outras palavras - A `margem-bottom` do conteúdo do corpo do site, deverá ser **igual ou maior** ao tamanho `height` do `footer`

```
footer {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   font-family:Gabriola;
   font-size:25px;
   color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
   background: rgba(73,155,234,1);
   background-size:cover;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(53,135,214,1);

   position:absolute; /* Adicionada a propriedade 'position absolute' */
}
```

No entanto esta pode **não ser a melhor forma** (na verdade não é) ou a mais adequada de o consertar, pois pode vir a sobrepor-se sobre outros elementos e causar uma má experiência ao usuário se não forem aplicados adequadamente.

Então a melhor maneira será pegar todo o elemento `footer` e mudá-lo, ou seja movê-lo para fora do *container/wrapper* que segura todo o conteúdo. Eu criei aqui um breve exemplo do que está acontecendo e o que podes fazer resolvê-lo.

## Exemplos:

- Esta é uma ideia de como ele se deve encontrar no momento - https://jsfiddle.net/av01m2qt/
- Este é um exemplo do como ele irá ficar se o mover para fora do *wrapper/container* - https://jsfiddle.net/av01m2qt/1/
- E este é um exemplo do primeiro método de que lhe falei em primeiro lugar, utilizando apenas a propriedade `position:absolute;` - https://jsfiddle.net/av01m2qt/2/

Answer (score 0):

Bem, acho que você pode fazer a seguinte tentativa.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #footer {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100px;
                position: static;
                bottom: 0px;
                left: 0px;

                background-color: #000
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            conteudo
            <br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1
            <br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>2
        </div>
        <div id="footer">&nbsp;</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Dê um UP se tiver servidor.